# Class keyword and prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, class, memory

Now in Javascript, after ECMAScript 6 one can declare classes with the class keyword, which is nice for programmers who come from Java like languages (myself too).

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    mult() {
        return this.a * this.b;
    }
}
```

But one can even use the prototype way of defining classes.

```
// The same code as above, but with prototype.
function MyClass(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
MyClass.prototype.mult = function() {
    return this.a * this.b;
}
```

Are these two definitions of MyClass the same? Why? Can anyone help me in differentiating between "class" way of defining classes and "prototype" way of defining classes based on memory consumption, performance etc.? Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you measure and get answers to your questions? As a JS developer, you worry about memory consumption between two different ways of declaring encapsulated code.. that's just pointless.

Comment: The above code is the same but classes have an abstraction of sub-classing through the `extends` keyword. Of course you can do the same without the classes but that would be a little more convoluted than the above comparison.

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 6 are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

It's simple syntax alternative to prototype way.

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 6 are syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript **classes** provide a much **simpler and clearer syntax to create objects** and deal with inheritance.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is almost the same, since `class` is just sugar.
The only difference I know is :

In this case

```
class MyClass() {}
```

you can't do `var obj = MyClass()` you must provide `new`. In the other case you can.